# relating data frames more efficiently

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one of hospital stays, and the other of lab results. I need to identify which hospital stay a lab result takes place in, and copy the admission and discharge dates from the hospital data frame into the row for the relevant lab result.

I am doing this with a for loop to walk through the lab results, and then if statements and subsets that look for matching entries (by patient SSN and surrounding dates) in the hospital records.

This is quite a large data set and using the for loop is very slow. Is there a way to speed this kind of problem up? (I have several similar problems, so would love an answer.)

Sample data added, note that there are multiple hospital records for each patient with the goal being to get the dates from the record where the dates overlap the lab date. In this example, the resulting data frame should only have admission and discharge dates for patient 1, as patient 2 has no hospital data, and patient 3's records do not overlap the lab date.

```
testDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-15", "2017-01-15", "2017-01-15"))
patientSSN <- c("1","2","3")
labs <- data.frame(patientSSN, testDate)

#   patientSSN   testDate
# 1          1 2017-01-15
# 2          2 2017-01-15
# 3          3 2017-01-15

patientSSN <- c("1","1","3","3")
admissionDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-07", "2017-02-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-16"))
dischargeDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-16", "2017-02-10", "2016-12-15", "2017-02-01"))
hospitalRec <- data.frame(patientSSN, admissionDate, dischargeDate)

for (I in 1:nrow(labs)) {
labs[I,]$admissionDate <- hospitalRec[hospitalRec$patientSSN == labs[I,]$patientSSN & hospitalRec$admissionDate <= labs[I,]$testDate & hospitalRec$dischargeDate >= labs[I,]$testDate,]$admissionDate

labs[I,]$admissionDate <- hospitalRec[hospitalRec$PatientSSN == labs[I,]$PatientSSN & hospitalRec$admissionDate <= labs[I,]$testDate & hospitalRec$dischargeDate >= labs[I,]$testDate,]$dischargeDate

}
```

The desired data frame would look like:

```
labs:
    patientSSN  testDate   admissionDate  dischargeDate
    1           2017-01-15 2017-01-07     2017-01-16
    2           2017-01-15 NA             NA
    3           2017-01-15 NA             NA
```

Notice, in the real data, there is also the problem of multiple hospital records qualifying (discharges between departments) these records would have the same admission date, but different discharge times with the latest one being important. But first things first...